# java.util.MissingResourceException when running a jar

Tags: java, resources, jar, classpath

In order to internationalise my code, I use a property file called MessagesBundle_en_UK.properties which is located in a resource folder called config so that I the following structure:

```
+---src
      \---com
            \---proj
                   \---messages
                              Messages.java  
+---config
         \---languages
                    MessagesBundle_en_UK.properties
```

Messages.java has:

```
    currentLocale = new Locale("en", "UK");
    messages = ResourceBundle.getBundle("MessagesBundle", currentLocale);
```

and I have added config/languages at the beginning of the classpath and it works fine when I run the program with javac/java from the command line.

---

My problem is that it doesn't work when I run the jar and I get this MissingResourceException error.

although the manifest does include config/languages:

```
    Class-Path: 
      ./config/languages 
      ./libs/xxxx.jar
      ./libs/...
      ...
```

I'm bit confused...

Thanks for the help
David

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should reference the location of your ResourceBundle relative to the root as if it were a member of a package:

```
messages = ResourceBundle.getBundle("config.lagnuages.MessagesBundle",currentLocale);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here is that you're trying to add a directory to the manifest `Class-Path` and but don't end it with a `/` character. From the [Extension Mechanism documentation](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/extensions/spec.html):

> An application (or, more generally, JAR file) specifies the relative URLs of the optional packages (and libraries) that it needs via the manifest attribute `Class-Path`. This attribute lists the URLs to search for implementations of optional packages (or other libraries) if they cannot be found as optional packages installed on the host Java virtual machine*. These relative URLs may include JAR files and directories for any libraries or resources needed by the application or optional package. **Relative URLs not ending with '/' are assumed to refer to JAR files.** For example,

```
Class-Path: servlet.jar infobus.jar acme/beans.jar images/
```

Most people bundle their properties files in their jars. For example:

```
+---jar_root
      \---com
            \---proj
                   \---messages
                              Messages.class
                              MessagesBundle_en_UK.properties
```

This bundle would have the name `"com.proj.messages.MessageBundle"`.